# Repeatable global declaration in C / GCC

Tags: c++, c, gcc

Short version:  Is there a way in C (and C++, compiled with GCC 6.4) to repeatedly declare a global variable within a translation unit?

Long version: Why on earth would I want to do that?  Well:

I'm trying to build CouchDB on Alpine Linux on ARMv6.  There is no pre-built CouchDB package for this platform (AFAICT).

CouchDB depends on SpiderMonkey / mozjs (the Mozilla javascript engine).  There is no pre-built mozjs package for this platform AFAICT (note that there **are** pre-built mozjs packages for Alpine on all non-ARM platforms).

SpiderMonkey wraps a bunch of system wrappers, for instance this version of `features.h`:

```
#pragma GCC system_header
#pragma GCC visibility push(default)
#include_next <features.h>
#pragma GCC visibility pop
```

The platform has `FORTIFY_SOURCE` installed.  So when the C++ standard library `#include`s `stdlib.h`, it gets `/usr/lib/fortify/stdlib.h` which does this:

```
__extension__
#include_next <limits.h>
```

The first thing `limits.h` does is:

```
#include <features.h>
```

After preprocessing, this ends up with:

```
__extension__
#pragma GCC system_header
#pragma GCC visibility push(default)
... contents of system features.h ...
#pragma GCC visibility pop
```

GCC whinges because `__extension__` has to be followed by an expression which is affected by the `__extension__`; it complains that `#pragma GCC visibility push(default)` isn't good enough.

The obvious thing to do is to patch SpiderMonkey's version of `features.h` to put a dummy declaration at the top of the file to keep GCC happy with the `__extension__` declaration.  But of course the file is included repeatedly, so it needs to be something I can repeat.

The code is being compiled with `-std=gnu99 -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-math-errno -pthread -pipe -g -freorder-blocks -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer`

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you asking how to declare and not define a variable?

Comment: I thought about `template<int> class Dummy {};` used with `__LINE__` somehow, but what about simply `extern int dummy;` defined somewhere once?

Comment: Perhaps even `__attribute__((unused)) extern int this_is_not_actually_a_real_symbol;`, which uses a real gcc extension.

Answer (score 1):

Of course non-definition declarations can be repeated. Definitions of objects, functions, and enumeration constants cannot (in C).

There is no need to declare an object, either. One might use simply `typedef char Unusedtype;`.